# How to clone an element?

Tags: javascript

I have made a script to clone elements in js but this only selects the first element. Here is the code :

```
 function clone(sel) {
     var rVxyz = document.querySelector(sel);
     var rVabc = rVxyz.cloneNode(true);
     document.body.appendChild(rVabc) || 
     document.documentElement.appendChild(rVabc);
 };
```

Yes I know I have used querySelector but I was not able to use it with querySelectorAll. I wrote something like this :

```
function clone(sel, num) {
    var rVxyz = document.querySelectorAll(sel)[num];
    var rVabc = rVxyz.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(rVabc) || 
    document.documentElement.appendChild(rVabc);
};
```

This only works when num = 0, otherwise it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `This only works when num = 0, otherwise it doesn't` - how many elements does `querySelectorAll` select? i.e. what is `sel` and what does your HTML look like?

Comment: querySelectorAll would select all elements with a common id or class or tagname.

Comment: ID's can't be common...they are unique by definition. Provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on what exactly you pass to your function as `sel`. If you are passing the id of an element, like this: `#someID`, there can only be 0 elements or 1 element in `rVxyz` as `id`s must be unique. So you can't clone that element, unless you include some code to change the ID, in which case it's not really a clone anyway.

Of course, if you are selecting by class, by passing something like `.someClass` to `sel`, then there can be any number of elements, from 0 to n.

I think it honestly makes more sense to clone all matching elements, rather than trying to pass an index to your function. So the `clone()` would use `forEach` instead.

```
function clone(sel) 
{
    var rVxyz = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
    rVxyz.forEach(function(element) {
         let rVabc = element.cloneNode(true);
         document.body.appendChild(rVabc) || 
         document.documentElement.appendChild(rVabc);
    });
};
 clone("#biz");                 
 clone(".boi");
 clone(".boi:nth-child(2)");
```

The HTML for test:

```
<div id="biz"><p>1 Unique thing</p></div>
<div class="boi"><p>2 hi</p></div>
<div class="boi"><p>hello there</p></div>
```

The output is:

1 Unique thing

2 hi

3 hello there

2 hi

3 hello there

2 hi

The first element is not cloned because IDs must be unique. Also, notice in the second call to `clone()`, I used the nth-child selector, so only the second matching element within each parent element is cloned. The nice thing about this is that you can even select every second, third, fourth, etc. element if you want.

As long as the elements are within the same parent container element, this will work.

Here's some [more info about nth-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/).

But your original approach would work as well if you actually want to clone the nth match. E.g. the 2nd match. You just need to check that you aren't going beyond the end of the `NodeList` rVxyz.

```
   function clone(sel, num) 
    {
       var rVxyz = document.querySelectorAll(sel);
       var limit = rVxyz.length;
       if (num < limit)
       {
          var rVabc = rVxyz[num].cloneNode(true);
          document.body.appendChild(rVabc) || 
          document.documentElement.appendChild(rVabc);
       }
      else
      {
         console.log(limit);//Do nothing or output error message here.
      }
    };

 clone(".boi", 1);
```

This clones the second matching element only, as long as there are 2 or more elements found.

Comment: yes it works but output isnot same . JS doesnot stop from making clone of element with id  ... so we can make clone of even <div id="biz"><p>1 Unique thing</p></div>

Answer (score 0):

But your code works... You just could add a few lines, to get less errors.

```js
function clone(sel, num) {
  num = parseInt(num);
  var id = !!sel.match('#');
  var elem = (id) ? document.querySelector(sel) : document.querySelectorAll(sel)[num];
  if (elem) {
    var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    clone.classList.add('demo'); // just for demo (remove);

    if (id || elem.id) {
      clone.id = elem.id + '-bubuClone';
      console.log( `New clone id="${clone.id}"` );
    }

    document.body.appendChild(clone) || document.documentElement.appendChild(clone);
  } else {
    console.log(
      'Didn\'t found element to clone: ("' + sel + '")' + ( !id ? '[' + num + ']' : '' ) 
    );
  }
}

clone('.test', 2);
clone('.test', 5);
clone('.test', 9);
clone('.test', 15);
clone('#bubu', 15);
clone('#check');
```

```css
.test, .test-id {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.demo {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-id" id="bubu">bubu</div>
<div class="test">0</div>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test" id="test007">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
<div class="test">7</div>
<div class="test">8</div>
<div class="test">9</div>
<br>
```

Or, add the third parameter to function, which will define the search type ( selector / selectorAll )